# Why is React onLeave={} being executed for every single page switch, instead only in the assigned one?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this route that I want to have some stuff executing when the user leaves it.

So I found the onLeave hook

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/layout" onLeave={ console.log("LEFT LAYOUT") } render={(props) => <GridLayoutApps retracted={this.state.sideBarRetracted} {...props}/>} />
</Switch>
```

Its supposed to console.log "Left layout" whenever I'm in /layout, and decide to load another route. Point is, this doesn't seem to happen, since the console.log is loading each time I switch ANY route.

I have the routes in my app.js file, which I

```
export default withRouter(App);
```

I have encapsulated it like this in index

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onLeave needs to be a function. At present its just an normal prop

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/layout" onLeave={() => {console.log("LEFT LAYOUT")} } render={(props) => <GridLayoutApps retracted={this.state.sideBarRetracted} {...props}/>} />
</Switch>
```

However please note that onLeave is not longer available in react-router v4 onwards and you need to use the `componentWillUnmount` or the `useEffect` hook to trigger the same behaviour